# Scroll speed is to fast in vs code via touchpad

Tags: visual-studio-code, scroll

I use Lenovo idea pad L340 laptop and when I use two finger to scroll the vs code screen, then the whole screen get scrolled from top to the bottom, this problem is also with the Power shell(in vs code Power shell and windows Power shell). I also enabled the smooth scroll option in the setting of vs code but nothing happened. Please give me a solution

adjusted scroll speed but no output

Answer (score 0):

Within VSCode you can try adjusting the value of this option in your settings.json file:

```
    "editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 4,
```

Also, you may also have to adjust the scroll speed in the system settings.

This article might be helpful for Windows users: [Can I change the touchpad scroll speed?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/can-i-change-the-touchpad-scroll-speed/8531d72e-bb1a-4fea-b94d-28be9d3221e9)